# JSONObject.toString() gives different result in 2.2 than in 2.1 (.Net Date format)

Tags: android, json, serialization, android-2.2-froyo, android-2.1-eclair

In Android 2.1 this

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
o.put("MyDate", "/Date(1289334937639)/");
Log.d(TAG, o.toString());
```

produces

```
{"MyDate":"/Date(1289334937639)/"}
```

but in 2.2 it produces

```
{"MyDate":"\/Date(1289334937639)\/"}
```

I am talking to a .Net web service so the 2.2 version works correctly for me.  How do I make 2.1 produce the same thing without breaking 2.2?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 7) {
    params = params.replaceAll("/", "\\\\/");
}
```

where params is the json already converted to a string.  Ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest version of of JSON from `http://www.json.org/java/` and integrate it to your code. You just need to change your imports I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I think I have the latest json version in eclipse, but it looks like the 2.1 emulator (and I confirmed this on a motorola droid running 2.1) uses a different version than the 2.2 emulator.  That is, the same code (same imports) produces two different results depending on the version of android.  Can I force the emulator/device to use the version of json I want it to use?